# Java API to turn on/off USB alarm light

Tags: java, api, usb, alarm

I have seen many simple alarm lights that can be plugged into a USB port.

I now need a Java API to be able to turn on/off one of these lights.

This seems like it would be a standard problem to have a appplication turn an alarm light on and off,  but I cannot find any simple solutions for it.

I just need a simple API where I can call "Light ON"  and "Light Off" and an external alarm light would start or stop flashing.

Any suggestions?

If needed I could also call it from a c# app.

Answer (score 0):

If your alarm light connects to USB, it might be able to communicate via a serial interface. You might want to check the device's documentation.

Also, this question is not very specific. I'm sure someone will flag this post soon